# What does it mean by "a process have or does not have superuser privileges"?

Tags: linux, unix, process, system-calls

From APUE

> There are  rules for who can change the IDs. Let’s consider only the
>   user ID for now. (Everything we describe for the user ID also applies
>   to the group ID.)
>
> 1. If the process has superuser privileges, the `setuid` function sets the real user ID, effective user ID, and saved set-user-ID to uid.
> 2. If the process does not have superuser privileges, but uid equals either the real user ID or the saved set-user-ID, `setuid` sets only the
>      effective user ID to uid. The real user ID and the saved set-user-ID
>      are not changed.
> 3. If neither  of  these  two  conditions  is  true, `errno` is  set  to `EPERM` and -1 is returned.

What does it mean by "a process have or does not have superuser privileges"?

Is it defined as whether the real user ID of the process is root or not?

Comment: The book covers all that pretty well. Just read it! Btw, `APUE` is obviously something that not everybody understands as `Advanced programming in the UNIX environment`

Comment: I've read the book myself and I will admit, this is definitely one of the more complicated sections. I too am not sure about this and I only finished it recently. Following this question closely!

Comment: @DanielPorteous Mostly complex things can be better understood by practice. If this is unclear I would recommend to write a small C program and play around with it. (I would also need to do it, I admit)